# jquery get text from dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that displays the JSON and allows the user to edit the text. After editing, I want to allow the user to click a button to save the new input value. Everything works as expected except for grabbing that new input value.

```
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObject.results.length; i++) {
    var row = `<tr scope="row" class="test-row-${jsonObject.results[i].id}">
    <td id="fName-${jsonObject.results[i].id}" data-testid="${jsonObject.results[i].id}">${jsonObject.results[i].firstName}</td>
    // some code

    $(`#save-${jsonObject.results[i].id}`).click(function(){
      clickAButton(jsonObject.results[i].id, jsonObject, i);
    });

    $(`#fName-${jsonObject.results[i].id}`).on('click', editResult)
    
}
```

```
function editResult(){
  var testid = $(this).data('testid')
  var value = $(this).html()

  $(this).unbind()
  $(this).html(`<input class="result form-control" data-testid="${testid}" type="text" value="${value}">`)
}
```

```
function clickAButton() {
  var text = $(`#fName-${jsonObject.results[index].id}`).val();
  console.log("text from " + text);
  // code
}
```

the code above displays

> text from

How do I get it to display the new user input?

Comment: Hi, how does `clickAButton()` gets called ?

Comment: @Swati i added the code. It's in the same original for loop

Comment: Are you able to access `jsonObject` and `index` variables inside `clickButton` function?

Comment: @KiranMahale yes, I am able to access ``jsonObject`` and ``index``. I'm worried that it is no longer that id due to unbinding?

Comment: As I understood you want to take the text between the `td` tag so it can be accessed by `textContent`.
Like 
`var text = $(`#fName-${jsonObject.results[index].id}`).textContent;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing mutliple event handler for all `tds` and `button` you can use only one event handler for button and td . So, when td is clicked just remove `data-testid` attribute from td so that again that event will not get called and to get input value use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.result').val()` this will give you input value where `save` button is clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var jsonObject = {
  "results": [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "sas"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "cd"
  }]
}

for (let i = 0; i < jsonObject.results.length; i++) {
  var row = `<tr scope="row" class="test-row-${jsonObject.results[i].id}">
    <td id="fName-${jsonObject.results[i].id}" data-testid="${jsonObject.results[i].id}">${jsonObject.results[i].firstName}</td><td><input type='button' id='save-${jsonObject.results[i].id}' value ='save'></td></tr>`

  $("table").append(row)
}

$(document).on('click', 'td[data-testid]', function() {
  var testid = $(this).data('testid')
  var value = $(this).html()
  $(this).html(`<input class="result form-control" data-testid = "${testid}" type = "text"
  value = "${value}" >`)
  //removed data-testid
  $(this).removeAttr("data-testid");
})

$(document).on('click', '[id*=save-]', function() {
  //use class to find input
  var text = $(this).closest('tr').find('.result').val();
  console.log("text from " + text);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```

Comment: how would this work if I had another field like last name? and want to grab everything in that line?

Comment: can you edit your question with complete code ?